# pure virtual method called only in GDB

Tags: crash, gdb, protocol-buffers

I am using google protocol buffer code in my program that works fine when I run my program normally, but crashes if I run it under gdb. Basically I receive the google proto class instance in a function via its input arguments as pointer and type cast it to the protocol buffer class and then call the `parseFromString` function which works normally. But if it run it under gdb I am getting *Pure virtual method* called error.

Appreciate anyone with some suggestions as to why this occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without code examples and a reference of the actual programming language you are using people can not help you. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

> Appreciate anyone with some suggestions as to why this occurs.

There are two likely causes: a data race (if your program is multi-threaded) or address layout sensitivity.

GDB affects timing of thread creation and destruction, and if you don't have proper synchronization between your threads, thread T1 may be trying to `ParseFromString` an object that has already been destructed by thread T2.

The other difference between running the program inside or outside GDB: GDB (by default) disables address randomization.

You can enable address randomization inside GDB with `set disable-randomization off`, and you can disable randomization outside GDB by running your program like so: `setarch $(uname -m) -R ./a.out`.